# cannot be applied to java.lang.String Java records

Tags: java, record

I'm just learning about get and set methods at uni. I feel like I am literally following the lecturer's notes word by word but I am getting errors:

> getZone(Station) in railwayStation cannot be applied to
>   java.lang.String

on the line with the code

```
int zone = getZone(station);
```

> getWheelchair(Station) in railwayStation cannot be applied to
>   java.lang.String

on the line with the code:

```
boolean wheelchair = getWheelchair(station);
```

What I was trying to do was create "train station" records and store information using set methods. I then later wanted to retrieve this information using get methods but I am getting the above errors. What did I do wrong?

```
//importing input functionality
import java.util.Scanner;
//creating a new record type station that holds records of stations
class Station {
    String stationName;
    int zone;
    boolean wheelchair;
}

public class railwayStation {
    public static void main(String []p) {
        //creating stations using set methods
        createStation("Bristol", 1,false);
        createStation("Reading", 2, true);
        createStation("York", 3,true);

        System.out.print("What station do you need to know about? ");

        //create scanner for input
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputStation = scanner.nextLine();

        getInfo(inputStation);

    }

    //creating set method
    public static Station createStation(String stationName, int zone, boolean wheelchair) {
        Station myStation = new Station();
        myStation.stationName = stationName;
        myStation.zone = zone;
        myStation.wheelchair = wheelchair;
        return myStation;
    }

    //creating get methods
    //getting station name
    public static String getName(Station myStation) {
        return myStation.stationName;
    }
    //getting station zone
    public static int getZone(Station myStation) {
        return myStation.zone;
    }
    //getting station wheelchair status
    public static boolean getWheelchair(Station myStation) {
        return myStation.wheelchair;
    }

    public static void getInfo(String station) {
        if(station.equals("Bristol")) {
            //get info using get methods
            int zone = getZone(station);
            boolean wheelchair = getWheelchair(station);
            if(wheelchair == false) {
                System.out.println(station + "is operated in zone " + zone + " and has no step free access");
            } else {
                System.out.println(station + "is operated in zone " + zone + " and has step free access");

            }


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `public static boolean getWheelchair(Station myStation)` expects a `Station` object, but you are passing `String station`

Comment: You're also not storing the stations. The code at the moment doesn't follow the contract of what I think you expect it to do, so I would recommend you work on being able to store the stations first before you try to access them.

Comment: @Compass I tried that before actually. It fixed it but gave me a similar response in the line "getInfo(inputStation)" where the error is "getInfo(Station) in railwayStation cannot be applied to java.lang.String"

Comment: @Compass aren't I storing the stations in the main method?

Comment: You're creating them, to be sure. You're not storing them anywhere. You return a station, but that station is never assigned anywhere, nor added to a collection.

Comment: @Compass so after creating a station I should save them in a variable for me to later access them?

Comment: Yes. Save them in a variable, then what you can do is search through your list of stations for a Station that matches a String name, and then return the wheelchair from that Station object.

Comment: @Compass Alright I think I get it, my lecturer didn't do this in his notes. Thank you.